# Numeric panel for web app

Tags: primefaces, commandbutton

I have to make a numeric panel to my web app but i can't find what action can insert value of button into text area. Can somebody help me?

```
<p:commandButton value="1" id="btn1"></p:commandButton>                       
<h:panelGrid id="grid" cellpadding="5" columns="1" >
<p:inputText id="liczby" style="width:245px" />
```

I have read that `onclick` function can do that but i don't know how to use it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please start here: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info the tutorials section. There are about 4 things at least wrong in 2 out of the 3 lines of code you post. Basic things...

Answer (score 0):

You might want the p:commandButton to update the state of a Java Object on the server, and then you want to bind your p:inputText to that value.

It would be more performant to handle this purely client-side, where the button element immediately updates the text element in the DOM, without request to the server, but that is something more difficult when you choose JSF.

You can't select by ID because you can't reliably predict the dynamically generated ID of the view element you target. You could use a class to select the inputText and modify it's value purely client side. It's a little awkward but should work.

```
<p:commandButton onclick="document.getElementsByClassName('myUniqueClass')[0].value = this.value" />
<p:inputText styleClass="myUniqueClass" />
```

Notes:

- you'll want to move the onclick functionality elsewhere, as it's an anti pattern to declare that functionality within your presentation.
- you're depending on yourself to not name another element 'myUniqueClass' so that you get exactly the element you expect. This is also a bit of an anti pattern. I believe primefaces offers a way of defining an ID instead, such that you can escape the dynamically generated ID (ie, not get the parent element ID injected into the current ID), and that might be a good way to get around this anti patterm

Comment: Hi, regarding the 'more difficult when you choose JSF', I only partly agree. If you know client-side html and are aware that in that regard jsf is merely an html generator, it is not that difficult (almost identical to what you would do without jsf). With the PrimeFaces commandButton, you need to be aware that adding `type="button"` makes it a purly client-side javascript aware button without sending anything to the server or updating anything.

Comment: Regarding the 'unreliably' use id's, if you want to use id's, you should make sure you assign explicit id's in every relevant place. Viewing the source and knowing what a naming container is, are the things to do/know. If you want help with this, Omnifaces comes to the rescue with the ['NoAutoGeneratedIdViewHandler'](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/viewhandlers/NoAutoGeneratedIdViewHandler)